# How do I solve this kind of sigma notation problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, notation

How do I solve the following? (by hand, its easy to find an answer with a calculator but I need an answer than can be done with some kind of rule/formula/identity).

$$\sum_{n=1}^5 n^n$$
and is there a certain rule i can use (by hand of course) that will let me solve this with any value instead of 5?

Thanks!

Comment: $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^Nn^n\simeq N^N$

Comment: $ +(N-1)^{N-1}$

Comment: What's that? ^^^

Answer (score 3):

I do not think there is a nicer closed form for this; you basically have to sum this by hand or with a computer to find the answer. Note that, for instance, it cannot be equal to any polynomial, because the terms grow faster than $x^k$ for any fixed $k$. Check out its entry in [the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C5%2C32%2C288&language=english&go=Search) for more references.